# Sharing a repository and Sharing development database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working with ruby on rails on Cloud9 and using BitBucket. What i would like to know is, when i share my BitBucket repository with someone to work with together on the same project, how can i ensure that they are able to see my development data as well?

Meaning if i have a Users table and i created 3 users in development, when they clone the git repository and work on their own Cloud9 server, would they be able to view the 3 users that i have created on my own workspace too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will not be able to view your data as it will be a different server. You can create a dump file of your database and share it.